# What does it mean when HP laptop beeping when trying to boot

Tags: boot, hp-pavilion

On an HP Pavilion dv5210us notebook PC, attempting to boot now results in four beeps and no progress yet power button remains lit.

I think this may mean the disk drive is no good and the computer cannot boot.

Is that correct, or is something else wrong?

Comment: More of a superuser question really. That being said, HP's website has a list of beep codes, 4 beeps, 3 beeps, etc., each has a different meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this table:

**[Troubleshooting Blink Codes or Beep Codes During Startup or Boot](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01732674&cc=uk&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3184205)**